# If a specific string is found, set as variable

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to assign a variable to a specific member of a list if it's found, but need to assign it to the human readable string first.

The original list is not human readable but can be interpreted using an API's GetName() function.

So to get my original list:

```
subFolders = rootFolder.GetSubFolderList()
```

To get that list as human readable:

```
for sub in subFolders:
    print(sub.GetName())
```

Now I'm trying to assign the variable 'Mmedia' if the string '02_media" is found in the human readable list.

```
for Mmedia in subFolders:
    if Mmedia.GetName() == '02_media':
        print('there is an 02_media folder')
else:
    print('no folder found')
```

any thoughts are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
Try the following:

```
good_folders = []
for Mmedia in subFolders:
    if Mmedia.GetName().find('02_media') >= 0:
        print('there is an 02_media folder')
        good_folders.append(Mmedia)
else:
    print('no folder found')
#at this point good_folders conatins list of the folders meeting criteria
```

Comment: `print (good_folders)`  results in just the brackets as written, so the list is not being contained when using the `.GetName()`  I think I need to find a different approach with this API.  Thank you for the suggestions and help.  I'll leave the original correct answer marked as correct, as I think the issue is more than my original question, which you've already answered.  Thanks again.

Comment: You showed earlier where Mmedia was a PyRemoteObject, there fore if you have included the line ```good_folders.append(Mmedia)``` good_folders should contain a list of Mmedia objects where Mmedia.GetName() returns a string containing '02_media'.

Comment: you are correct, good_folders does return the APIs PyRemoteObject, but using the APIs GetName() of that object returns an error.  I need to define good_folders to use the GetName() function... EDIT it is defined if I create a separate variable after good_folders is defined.  So adding `for gf in good_folders: print (gf.GetName()`returns the good folder as human readable!  Thank you so much for pointing out the PyRemoteObject again.... this worked

Answer (score 1):

assuming the function GetName returns a string:
replace the line of code:
`if Mmedia.GetName == '02_media':`

with:
`if Mmedia.GetName().find('02_media') >= 0:`

Comment: now I know you can't assign a string to a class instantiation, so I'd first need to assign `Mmedia` to a class?

Comment: subFolders returns `[<PyRemoteObject object at 0x0000023F806C1360>, <PyRemoteObject object at 0x0000023F806C1378>, <PyRemoteObject object at 0x0000023F806C1390>, <PyRemoteObject object at 0x0000023F806C13A8>, <PyRemoteObject object at 0x0000023F806C13C0>]` and

`for sub in subFolders: print (sub.GetName())`

returns

`SFX
04_Media
03_Media
02_Media
VFX`

Comment: now that I'm seeing it this way, `GetName()` returns a string not a list

Comment: Yes, and the same class thatv offers the GetName() method should also provide a SetName() method so that you can modify the name

Comment: Mmedia is an instantiation of a class represented by each entry in SubFolders.  To determine the class, you would need to identify where the SubFolders list is built.

Comment: the API i'm using does not offer a `SetName` however it does offer a `SetCurrentFolder` so I think it's a limitation of the API, and I would have to use a set folder structure in order to use the  `if Mmedia.GetName().find('02_Media') >= 0: ` the API doesn't allow for the loop: for folders contained in the root folder, if a certain folder exists, then set that as the current folder, and move files to it.  unless you can think of some other way around that.

Comment: What api are you using?

Comment: I am not sure of what you want to do?  Do you want to identify specific folders containing the string '02_Media' and then (a) rename the folder?, (b)capture the name /path for later access, (c)other?

Comment: capture the name/path for later access would probably be the closest thing I'm trying to do.  The basic frame work would be to: find if a certain folder exists, if it does tell me it does, and assign that folder as a variable, so I can use other API functions with that assigned folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `any` to check for a `True` value in a collection of boolean values like `(item.find(substring) >=0 for item in items)`. This makes the code a bit more cleaner:

```
items = ["prefix_01_suffix", "prefix_02_suffix"]

def test(substring):
    if any(item.find(substring) >=0 for item in items):
        print (f"substring {substring} exists")
    else:
        print(f"substring {substring} doesn't exist")

test("01")
test("02")
test("03")
```

Comment: thanks Nishant, this is very interesting and will dig more into it.  It's actually got me thinking on one of the next steps I need to do, and this does look like an approach to do it with